# Prepared statement: Compare timestamp with granularity of minutes

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timestamp, prepared-statement

I've got a `PreparedStatement` created with an SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE MY_DATE = ?
```

I set the `MY_DATE` value with

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, myDate);
```

This way the database checks if the whole timestamp is equal.

Now I want to reduce the granularity of the just to minutes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: From a performance point of view, use an explicit range condition. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **TRUNC** would suppress any **regular index on the date column**. One way to improve performance is to create a **function-based index**.

However, the better way is to use an **explicit range condition**.

For example,

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE
  MY_DATE >= TO_DATE('24-MAR-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
  AND MY_DATE < TO_DATE('24-MAR-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')+1;
```

Or,

Using **BETWEEN** (which would anyway be re-written as the above range condition by the Optimizer):

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE
  MY_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('24-MAR-2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
  AND TO_DATE('24-MAR-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') + (1-1/24/60/60);
```

**Some more information**

With the range condition, the optimizer actually rewrites the query in the following way:

```
access("MY_DATE">=TO_DATE(' 2015-03-24 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND
              "MY_DATE"<TO_DATE(' 2015-03-24 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

And there will be an `INDEX RANGE SCAN` operation instead of `TABLE ACCESS FULL`. In case of using **TRUNC**, without a function based index, this is how the optimizer applies the filter predicate:

```
filter(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("MY_DATE"))=TO_DATE(' 2015-03-24 00:00:00',
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

A nice article to read about [Impact of the TRUNC Function on an Indexed Date Column](https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/impact-of-the-trunc-function-on-an-indexed-date-column/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the TRUNC() function, then you can ignore the granularity of the value, below a certain level.

So, in your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE TRUNC(MY_DATE, 'MI') = TRUNC(?, 'MI')
```

Other granularities are available: see [Oracle's Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2071.htm#CJAEFAIA) for details (the default is to truncate to 00:00:00 on the relevant date).

Of course, if your stored timestamps are already truncated to the minute, then you can leave out that left-hand invocation of TRUNC, and take advantage of an index, if there is one on that column.

Comment: You do not want to call TRUNC on MY_DATE as it may invalidate use of an index.

Comment: Not a good idea to use **TRUNC** if you have an **indexed** column. Better use a range condition.